# This C program doesn't work

Tags: c, console-application, getchar

I copied the following C code from K&R. The code is supposed to print a line if it is currently the longest line typed by the user.
This is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
int max;
char line[MAXLINE];
char longest[MAXLINE];

int getline();
void copy();


int main(){

    int len=0;
    extern int max;
    extern char longest[];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline()) > 0)
        if (len > max){

            max = len;
            copy();
        }

    if (max > 0){

        printf("%s", longest);
    }
    return 0;
 }


    int getline(){

    int c;
    int i;
    extern char line[];

    for(i = 0; i < MAXLINE-1
        &&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';++i)
            line[i] = c;

    if(c=='\n'){
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;



}




      void copy(){

      int i;
      extern char line[];
      extern char longest[];

       i=0;

       while((longest[i]=line[i])!='\0')
        ++i;
      }
```

The problem is that it doesn't appear to work. Running the code, I can type lines into the console but it doesn't print the longest line. I would appreciate any help.

EXTRA INFO:
I7m using Win7 with Open Watcom compiler.
The console doesn't fold, it lets me input characters.
Also, I'm not sure that I am stuck in a loop because if I change my while-loop in main() to

```
while((len = getline()) > 0)
        if (len > max){
            printf("IT WORKS");
            max = len;
            copy();
        }
```

with a print command if the length of the line is longer than the current max-length, then "IT WORKS" is printed on screen. So it is definitely counting line lengths.

Comment: Sounds like you copied it wrong.  Assume that it's you; K&R has been around for a very long time.  If there was a bug in the examples, someone would have spotted it decades ago.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Just some extra info: its from K&R page 32. I'm can't see any differences between mine and the book version. It might be my compiler (just a wild guess). I'm using the Open Watcom 16-bit compiler.

Comment: What museum did you break into to get that one?  You might have to press and hold down the BREAK key on the teletype.

Comment: Well, I go through K&R in my lunch break on my netbook. Open Watcom is a nice little compiler (IMHO). I could boot up Visual Studio, but it seems overkill just to do these little K&R exercises. Also my netbook is on its last legs

Comment: @ domanokz, please see my edited Question... yes I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: @JJG Please see my edited answer, it works... The `getline` function returns 1 higher than expected length of the word entered. Also, add `getch` before `return 0` on your `main` function to ensure that the console wont exit until you press a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getline` returns 1 higher than expected, so if the user just hits enter, it doesnt exit the loop. Also, add `getch()` before `return 0` in your `main` function, the console exits/folds after printing the longest line. Many books have the same example so if you want the console to remain open, put `getch` so the user should strike a key before the program exits. Here, try these codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
int max;
char line[4];
char longest[MAXLINE];

int getline();
void copy();


int main()
{
    int len=0;
    extern int max;
    extern char longest[];

    max = 0;
            /* put -1 to getline so it will return the right length... */ 
    while(((len = getline()) - 1) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d \n",len);
        if (len > max)
        {

            max = len;
            copy();
        }
    }

    if (max > 0)
    {

        printf("%s", longest);
    }

            /* Put getch() or getchar() so console will wait for a key to be pressed before exiting */
    getch();
    return 0;
 }


int getline()
{

    int c;
    int i;
    extern char line[];

    for(i = 0; i < MAXLINE-1 &&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';++i)
    {
        line[i] = c;
    }

    if(c=='\n')
    {
        line[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}




      void copy(){

      int i;
      extern char line[];
      extern char longest[];

       i=0;

       while((longest[i]=line[i])!='\0')
        ++i;
      }
```

Comment: Presumably on the assumption that JJG is running on windows and the console is folding up as soon as the program exits?

Comment: I think so... It exits immediately after printing the line.

Comment: It copies and prints the longest line, as you said. But it folds after one line of input. Is this supposed to happen? BTW thanks.

Comment: @JJG - What do you mean by folds? ?_? If it answers your question, please mark answered. Thanks! :)

Comment: I also think that getch is not normally available, you need to include maybe windows.h or something like that, or maybe conio.h

Comment: @domanokz - sorry, I thought "folds" means the console window disappears. I'm in Windows. I want the console to stay open but it disappears after one lline of input and then pressing return. Maybe I should do tese exercises in Linux.

Comment: @JJG - I'm using Windows too. Please see my revisions. It should work now! :)

Answer (score 5):

In fact it does, but it won't stop reading lines until you type an [*end-of-file* character.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

This is ^D on Unix/Mac and ^Z on Windows. (But note that Windows doesn't really implement terminal-EOF, so it is up to your library or something like Cygwin to interpret the ^Z.)

If your window is only active when the program is running I suppose a `sleep(5)` might be a good idea at the very end of main().  It would really be best to run console I/O programs like this from a long-lived window like Terminal on the mac or the DOS box on Windows.

Comment: Or simply change this line `while((len = getline()) > 0)` to this: `while((len = getline()) > 1)`. Now you can just hit enter on an empty line to get out.

Comment: Thanks. OK, so I typed control-Z after typing a line and the console collapsed. What is the best way to keep it open?

Comment: Ok..good. See the answer below here: either use getch() at end of main(), or add sleep() as Ross suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here, but I think what you're missing is that you need to send EOF to getchar() to get out of the loop.

I think you're running this on Linux, right? If so, simply press CTRL-D (which means EOF on Linux/Unix) on an empty line, and your program will exit the loop and print out the longest line.